# Change style on only one <li> when clicking it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Dears, I'm doing a web app with a sidebar. When I click on a "li" element, I want it turns into bold. All the informations from my sidebar are retrieve from a Json file which contains 2 objects of 1 array. The first one which name is "Brand" contains 6 pages (with name, logo component parameters) and the second one which name is "Components" contains 12 pages. In order to display them, I do a first map on the main group "Brand" and "Components" and then a second map on the pages of each group. But when I selected a "li" item, it put in bold the first "li" of Brand and Components in the same time whereas I just want the one clicked

I did a State with -1 as non existed element and and handle click with the setState. On the "li" element, I put into the style the condition

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Data from './menu.json';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


export default class MainMenu extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selected: -1
        };
    }
    handleClick = (index) => { 
        console.log("index")
        this.setState({
            selected: index
        })
    }


    render(){

        return (
            <div className="MainMenu" > 
        {
            Data.map(
                (item, index) => <div key={index}>
                    <h2 className="Title" >{item.group}</h2>
                    <ul className="List"> 
                        {item.pages.map((page, i) => 
                        <li 
                            key={i} 
                            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} 
                            style={ this.state.selected === i ? { fontWeight: 'bold' } : { fontWeight: 'normal' } }>                            
                            <Link to={page.url} className="ListItem">{page.name}</Link>
                        </li>)}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            )
        }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect only on

turn into bold when I click on it and not two due to the double map

Comment: try extracting it into a function and see if onclick it goes into the function and set style from there. check console.

Comment: Is the `console.log("index")` being called?

Comment: You have multiple lists so you need to keep a selected index for each list. Your click handler needs to include the `index` of the list, and the handler function needs to set the specific element of the state array. A simpler way maybe would be to put each list in a separate component managing its own state, depending on how the selection is ultimately handled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use classNames https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

for conditional className rendering, so you can do this after setting the clicked item index in the state:

`<li 
className={
classnames({boldWeight: this.state.selectedItem === i},normalWeight:this.state.selectedItem !== i})
}></li>`